# str to float error in csv python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, python-2.7, floating-point

I'm trying to open a csv file that is 10 columns x 100 rows and I first want to swap it to 100 columns x 10 rows, which I believe I used the zip function properly for, and then make 10 arrays with a 100 floats in each.

```
output = []
with open("undercurve.csv",'rU') as f5:
    reader = csv.reader(f5, delimiter= ',')
    reader1 = zip(*reader)
    for row in reader1:
        value = 0 
        for i in row:
            value = float(i)
            output.append(i)
```

However, when I run it I get a

```
    ValueError
    Traceback (most recent call last)

        174             else:
        175                 filename = fname
    --> 176             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
        177     else:
        178         def execfile(fname, *where):

    C:\Users\Robert\Downloads\May.py in <module>()
        142         value = 0
        143         for i in row:
    --> 144             value = float(i)
        145             output.append(i)
        146 
    ValueError: could not convert string to float.
```

I'm guessing this is from the previous part:

```
i = 0
with open("undercurve.csv",'w') as f3:
    for i in undercurve_1:
        mean = i
        variance = .2
        points = undercurve(1000)[:10]
        for item in points:
            x = str(item)
            f3.write(x + ",")
        f3.write("\n")
```

If I try to use x = float(item), I get an error:

```
    TypeError                                 
    Traceback (most recent call last)
    174             else:
    175                 filename = fname
--> 176             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    177     else:
    178         def execfile(fname, *where):

C:\Users\Robert\Downloads\May.py in <module>()
    130         for item in points:
    131             x = float(item)
--> 132             f3.write(x + ",")
    133         f3.write("\n")
    134 
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'.
```

I'm not exactly sure as to what to do in this situation.

```
0.485863651248,0.0387115424974,0.287431660408,0.368734594828,0.618990463984,0.112220965205,0.418700402941,0.193754757929,0.573411295973,-0.192370410069,
-1.42282833703,-1.52808081061,-1.03071829996,-1.00330662742,-1.23896275168,-1.09742340137,-0.940839402591,-0.918657969034,-1.37832945051,-0.932452513278,
```

These are just the first 2 lines of the undercurve.csv file

Comment: Please do include full tracebacks, not just the exception. Without more information about what is *in* your CSV file it is also impossible to tell what might be the cause of this.

Comment: Try adding `float(i.strip())`

Comment: @drewk: `float()` ignores whitespace; it *already* strips the input.

Comment: What does `undercurve(1000)[:10]` do?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You sly dog -- you are right again!

Comment: gimme a bit i'll  fix the traceback. But the undercurve(1000)[:10] simply just takes 10 random digits under a gaussian

Comment: I would post my csv file in here, I'm just not 100% sure as to how

Comment: @RobertKhachatryan: Just the first few rows will do; indent to 4 spaces just like you do with code and tracebacks.

Comment: @RobertKhachatryan: from your other question I am gathering you have rows with one text column and the rest float columns; you can convert all the float columns by skipping the text column (after `zip()` that is the first row).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thats what I thought at first but when I looked at the file there are no letters. Its all digits and yet it believes that there are non-integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the end of each line of your file ends with a comma. This makes a '' (empty string) appear. And float('') gives you the ValueError.

Comment: Oh wow. I did not notice that. How should go about fixing that?

Comment: @RobertKhachatryan: ignore the last row of your transposed list: `for row in reader1[:-1]:`