# Convert Python list of strings into floats, where list also contains words

Tags: python, string, list, floating-point

Consider for example the list in Python containing both strings of letters and numbers

```
a = ['Total', '1', '4', '5', '2']
```

How would it be possible to convert this into the mixed value list

```
b = ['Total', 1.0, 4.0, 5.0, 2.0]
```

Note that in general we may not know where the letters string will be in the list i.e. we might have

```
a = ['Total', '1', '4', 'Next', '2']
```

Comment: Should `b[0]` always be a string, even if `a[0].isdigit() == True`?

Comment: Or, can you assert that `a[0].isdigit() == False`?

Comment: I was personally looking for a general way to go about it i.e a[3] might have been a string (within the string) also.

Comment: Not sure if I follow, could you add an example of that to the question?

Comment: Hopefully the example has cleared that up

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. Ashwini has the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a generator function and exception handling:

```
>>> def func(seq):
        for x in seq:
            try:
                yield float(x)
            except ValueError:
                yield x
...             
>>> a = ['Total', '1', '4', '5', '2']
>>> list(func(a))
['Total', 1.0, 4.0, 5.0, 2.0]
```

Comment: Beat me to it. +1, and a small edit to correct the indentation.

Answer (score 4):

Just convert everything but the first column:

```
b = a[:1] + [float(i) for i in a[1:]]
```

Judging from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781344/str-to-float-error-in-csv-python) you are processing a CSV file, so if the first column is always a string there is no point in converting that part of each row:

```
>>> a = ['Total', '1', '4', '5', '2']
>>> a[:1] + [float(i) for i in a[1:]]
['Total', 1.0, 4.0, 5.0, 2.0]
```

You could also use a `try:` - `except ValueError` approach, but why incur the overhead when it is known up front what column has text and what columns have numeric values?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your end goal isn't a csv package, I'd recommend pandas.read_csv.