# Floating a double list?

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I have been reading this page [Convert Python list of strings into floats, where list also contains words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781352/convert-python-list-of-strings-into-floats-where-list-also-contains-words?rq=1)

And tried to implement this but I can't for a double list.

I have a double list that looks like this

```
Positions = [['ace','first', '10','-29'],['best','second','200','-10']]
```

This is what I get from opening a file. What I would like to do is remove the strings from the 2nd and 3rd index spots in the list so as to get both these positions as integers and not strings. Is there a way that I can open the file to mp remove these strings

or

is there a way that I can remove the strings by applying a method to my double list??

Answer (score 2):

Get a list of lists, where each sublist has the int represented in the last two positions of each sublist in `Positions`:

```
[[int(i) for i in L[-2:]] for L in Positions]
```

Turn the string representations of the integers in `Positions` into `int`s:

```
[[int(i) for i in L if ((i.startswith('-') and all(char.isdigit() for char in i)) or all(char.isdigit() for char in i) else i] for L in Positions]
```

Comment: Interesting yet different slightly to first answer I saw. I will try this too and see how it goes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you have is nested loops. It's pretty much the same:

```
>>> L = [['ace','first', '10','-29'],['best','second','200','-10']]
>>> for i in L:
...     i[3] = int(float(i[3]))
...     i[2] = int(float(i[2]))
...     
... 
>>> print L
[['ace', 'first', 10, -29], ['best', 'second', 200, -10]]
```

Comment: Hi I've tried this for another list but it doesn't work at one point as there is a decimal involved in the second position so it's '10.30' for an example.?? Is there a way to strip these with decimals??