# Cast list of lists to floats while ignoring column of strings

Tags: python, string, list, floating-point

Very similar to the question: [Convert Python list of strings into floats, where list also contains words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781352/convert-python-list-of-strings-into-floats-where-list-also-contains-words)

Except I have a 2 Dimensional list (a list of lists) and the structure is predictable.

```
aa,3,250
bb,2,225
cc,4,275
dd,2.5,200
```

The first column is always populated with strings and should be left alone.  I am trying to convert the rest of the lists to floats for later use.

```
import csv

data = open('import.csv', 'r')
catdata = csv.reader(data,delimiter=',')
cats = []
for row in catdata:
    cats.append(row)    

#trying to do the conversion here
cats = cats[:1] + [map(float, x) for x in cats[1:]]

numrowcats = len(cats)

for i in xrange(numrowcats):
    sol=cats[i][1]+cats[i][2]
    print sol
```

And here is the error:

```
File "theworldneedsmorecats.py", line 12, in <module>
    cats = cats[:1] + [map(float, x) for x in cats[1:]]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: bb
```

It appears as though I have successfully skipped the first string and it is now hung up on the second one "bb".

And if I remove the conversion line I get:

```
3250
2225
4275
2.5200
```

Questions:  Is there a way to tweak the logic to convert the numbers to floats while ignoring the strings in column 0?  Can this be done with as little overhead as possible?  Since this is being imported, is there a 'smarter' way to import them in the correct format to begin with?

EDIT:  The following works, thanks-

```
import csv

data = open('import.csv', 'r')
catdata = csv.reader(data,delimiter=',')
cats = []
#the line below appends AND casts data from the csv
cats = [c[:1] + map(float, c[1:]) for c in catdata]

print (cats)
print cats[0][0]
```

and the output:

```
[['aa', 3.0, 250.0], ['bb', 2.0, 225.0], ['cc', 4.0, 275.0], ['dd', 2.5, 200.0]]
aa
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your first element in your array is not the first column, but the first row. Thus your line

```
cats = cats[:1] + [map(float, x) for x in cats[1:]]
```

tries to convert all the elements except those in the first *row* to float, which fails.

Instead, you could do the casting when you add the individual rows to `catdata`. You can do this in a single line as a list comprehension, replacing your `for row in catdata` loop with just this:

```
>>> cats = [c[:1] + map(float, c[1:]) for c in catdata]
>>> print(cats)
[['aa', 3.0, 250.0],
 ['bb', 2.0, 225.0],
 ['cc', 4.0, 275.0],
 ['dd', 2.5, 200.0]]
```

Comment: This formats the data correctly but still cuts off the first row.  Code and output added to my Edit above.

Comment: @nodoze Sorry, should have been clearer (edited): Do not _add_ that line to your loop, but _replace the entire loop_ with that line. (If you put it in the loop, the first line is consumed by the loop, then the remaining lines are consumed by the list comprehension, then the iterator is exhausted and the loop ends.)

Comment: and there it is. interesting that I can replace the entire loop.  I see the 'built-in' for-loop (for c in catdata) but exactly how is it extracting the data from my CSV?  map?

Comment: @nodoze Well, your initial for loop can be rewritten as a list comprehension like `cats = [row for row in catdata]`. You could also put my list comprehension after that, looping over cats: `cats = [c[:1] + map(float, c[1:]) for c in cats]`, but since `cats` holds just the lines from `catdata`, you can just as well use `catdata` directly. Hope this makes things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
import csv

data = open('import.csv', 'r')
catdata = csv.reader(data,delimiter=',')
cats = []
for row in catdata:
    cats.append(row)

catsNoFirstColumn = [cats[i][1:] for i in range(len(cats))]

catsFloat = [map(float, catsNoFirstColumn[i]) for i in range(len(catsNoFirstColumn))]
```

gives you:

```
[[3.0, 250.0], [2.0, 225.0], [4.0, 275.0], [2.5, 200.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a code like here. Please take care this works just your sample case. The logic is simple. It just quote nonnumeric characters ,then use csv.reader.

```
import csv
import StringIO
import re

convertedText = re.sub(r'([^\d,.\n]+)', r'"\1"', open("import.csv").read())
fp = StringIO.StringIO(convertedText)
reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
for line in reader:
    print line
```

output:

```
['aa', 3.0, 250.0]
['bb', 2.0, 225.0]
['cc', 4.0, 275.0]
['dd', 2.5, 200.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a list of lists:

```
data=[]     
with open(fn, 'r') as fin:
    for row in csv.reader(fin):
        data.extend([[row[0]]+[float(e) for e in row[1:]]])
```

Results in:

```
[['aa', 3.0, 250.0], ['bb', 2.0, 225.0], ['cc', 4.0, 275.0], ['dd', 2.5, 200.0]]
```

It appears to me, though, that this data really wants to be a dictionary:

```
data={}        
with open(fn, 'r') as fin:
    for row in csv.reader(fin):
        data[row[0]]=[float(e) for e in row[1:]]
```

Results in data being:

```
{'dd': [2.5, 200.0], 'cc': [4.0, 275.0], 'bb': [2.0, 225.0], 'aa': [3.0, 250.0]}
```

Then you can access the elements like so:

```
>>> data['dd']
[2.5, 200.0]
```